# Как поднять проект на своем сервере? Подключить composer к выкачаному проекту

Tags: php, composer

Привет. Есть проект,который выкачал его через GiT и запихнул я его в  `htdocs/site` (xampp). Теперь задача стоит поднять этот проект на моем сервере.
Установил `composter` на `xampp`.
Он у меня доступен 
`С:/xamppp/php/php composer.phar`
Если я создаю проект:

```
С:/xamppp/php/php composer.phar create project C:/...htdocs/site/
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Error:InvalidArgumentExeption Cannot find project with stability stable

Еще делал так :

```
create-project --repository-url='адрес где проект/composer.json' C:/...htdocs/site/(куда ставлю)...
```

Так вот оно выбило ошибку

> Invalid repozitory giver/Must http or file json(так я подкючаю composer.json). У меня в проекте есть файл composer.json где прописаны все зависимости

Comment: сделайте 

    cd C:/...htdocs/site/(куда ставлю)...
    С:/xamppp/php/php composer.phar create-project

Но по всей видимости, если вы уже проект ручками скачали, то вместо второй команды нужно набрать

    С:/xamppp/php/php composer.phar install

а в дальнейшем, при изменении зависимостей, использовать

    С:/xamppp/php/php composer.phar update

Comment: Johny сейчас попробую...Очень благодарен за какой-либо совет.

Answer (score 1):

я всегда делаю так

1. `git clone url/project.git`
2. `cd project`
3. `composer install` в вашем случае (`С:/xamppp/php/php composer.phar install`)

вот и всё, других способов я не знаю